# Help Me Remember: A Developer Reference App

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications, development, documentation

everyone. I'm trying to remember a macOS application that I used to use. It could be opened with a keyboard command within almost any application or the Finder, and it would pop up a dialog to search reference material for different developer languages, frameworks, tools, etc. I thought it was Alfred, but looking over the website, that doesn't look familiar. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash). It has a [global search keyboard shortcut feature](https://kapeli.com/dash_guide#globalSearchShortcut) as well as a host of others for searching developer documentation.

Here's an overview of the app from its website:

> Dash is an API Documentation Browser and Code Snippet Manager. Dash instantly searches offline documentation sets for 200+ APIs, 100+ cheat sheets and more.

And a summary of the global shortcut feature:

> The global search shortcut is an easy way to activate Dash in a similar style as the Spotlight shortcut. You can assign a search shortcut in Preferences > General and then use that hotkey in any app when you want to bring up Dash. You can also assign a shortcut to search using the selected text.